# Rebuilding non-completing Observable Array after decomposing with mergeMap and transforming

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a Subject with publishReplay and refcount, so it effectively never completes. The output of the refcount is an Observable array of objects. I would like to decompose the Observable object array into emitted elements, transform as needed, and then merge them back into an array, but since the source is non-completing, the array boundary is 'lost' in the asynchronous nature.

As an example, I use mergeMap and scan to accumulate the data. However, as expected, it continually accumulates, so the resulting array is the entire history of the stream. The initial value of the scan is only initialized at the beginning of the stream. I can't use toArray, because the Observable never terminates.

I have a lot of experience in asynchronous hardware design. The hardware analogy to this asynchronous chain is using a latch. I'm not sure what the conceptual equivalent is in RxJS. I would assume taking the emitted array output from refcount and applying it to Observable.from(theArrayOutput) would work, but I can't figure out how to insert it in the chain of streams.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

type IObjectsOperation = (types: Object[]) => Object[];

@Component({
    selector: 'app-events-test',
    templateUrl: './events-test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./events-test.component.css']
})

export class EventsTestComponent implements OnInit {
    public objects: Observable<Object[]>;
    public scanned: Observable<any>;
    protected updates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    protected functionStream: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    protected addStream: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();
    private initialObjects: Object[] = [1];

    constructor() {
        this.objects = this.updates
            .scan((objects: Object[],
                   operation: IObjectsOperation) => {
                    return operation(objects);
                },
                this.initialObjects)
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount();
        this.functionStream
            .map(function (message: Object): IObjectsOperation {
                return (messages: Object[]) => {
                    return messages.concat(message);
                };
            })
            .subscribe(this.updates);
        this.addStream.subscribe(this.functionStream);
        this.scanned = this.objects
            .mergeMap(val => val)
            // some transformation that I want to have happen, in this case no-op
            .filter(() => {return true})
            // attempt to rebuild array, but items are accumulated
            .scan( (acc: Array<any>, x: Object) => { return acc.concat(x); }, [])

    }


transform(objects) {
    return Observable.from(objects)
        // this withLatestFrom suggestion didn't work
        // .withLatestFrom( this.functionStream, ( val, fn ) => fn( val ) )
        .filter(() => {
            return true
        })
        .toArray()
}


    start(): void {
        console.log('---------STARTING');
        this.objects.mergeMap(obj => this.transform(obj))
        .subscribe(
            obj => console.log('objects: ' + obj)
        );
        this.scanned.subscribe(
            {
                next: obj => {
                    console.log('scanned: ' + obj);
                },
                error: () => {
                },
                complete: () => console.log('COMPLETED')
            }
        );
        this.add(2);
        this.add(3);
    }
    add(object: Object): void {
        this.addStream.next(object);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.start();
    }

}
```

The output is below, and expected.

```
---------STARTING
events-test.component.ts:49 objects: 1,2
events-test.component.ts:52 scanned: 1
events-test.component.ts:52 scanned: 1,2
events-test.component.ts:49 objects: 1,2,3
events-test.component.ts:52 scanned: 1,2,1
events-test.component.ts:52 scanned: 1,2,1,2
events-test.component.ts:52 scanned: 1,2,1,2,3
```

What I would like to see is:

```
---------STARTING
events-test.component.ts:49 objects: 1,2
events-test.component.ts:52 scanned: 1,2
events-test.component.ts:49 objects: 1,2,3
events-test.component.ts:52 scanned: 1,2,3
```

I have a few workarounds that I can use:

1. Keep the data as an array throughout the stream
2. Convert the source non-completing observable to completing

I would assume the solutions for this architecture are:

1. There is some operation I can insert into the stream to take the array from objects Observable, and return an observable that completes
2. There is some external signal that needs to occur from the source Observable that indicates 'processing' and then the termination bounds the scan. This seems clumsy to me.

I would assume there would be some equivalent in RxJS to a asynchronous hardware latch, so I'd like to keep the current architecture. Additionally, I think RxJS is really cool and want to close a gap in my knowledge in terms of time based handling of streams.

EDIT: A good answer from @xtianjohns indicated how to do an inner loop, but the subscription still does not complete. The suggested addition of withLatestFrom caused the transform function to break, in commenting out that line, the array is rendered, but the outer loop does not complete. If the line is present, the array is not rendered, and the loop does not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from using `mergeMap` followed by `scan`, and doing so on the "outer" stream, rather than transforming your list of objects and then emitting that list.

Another way: if what you want is a stream of arrays, then let's always keep it a stream of arrays.

```
        /* Function that takes array and returns stream of transformed arrays */
        function transform( objects ) {
          return Observable.from( objects )
            /* We only need this because your transformation is wrapped in a stream. */
            .withLatestFrom( this.functionStream, ( val, fn ) => fn( val ) )
            // some transformation that I want to have happen, in this case no-op
            .filter(() => {return true});
            .toArray();
        }

        this.scanned = this.objects
          /* let's keep this as Observable<Array<YourObject>> */
          .mergeMap( transform );
          /* No need to "rebuild" array, this is now a stream of arrays */
```

Note how in this example, I "transform" the elements of the array inside `transform`, rather than trying to "unwrap" the array in the stream and then recompose.

Does this fit your use case?

EDIT: I made a mistake reading your functionStream signature, have corrected this.

Comment: The problem is the transformation (the filter) occurs on individual emitted elements. I still have the same problem when it comes to the filter(my transformations) they have to occur on each item. Think along the getting links in the main stream, and then for each item searching another observable for the linked item. It's pretty cool though, I might have misled you a bit by including the functionStream. It's really just a means to load the Subject from the addStream, nothing else. I'm not quite sure how that transform function is working, I'll keep working on it and get back to you.

Comment: Not a problem, if all you need is the filter to run on each item, then we can just move that inside the transform function also. You just move all of the transformations or validations on individual elements inside of the "transform" function, which you can name or refactor however you like. Post is now edited.

Comment: This is almost working, it's just not completing. I edited the subscription in the code to look for complete, and added an EDIT comment to indicate the issue. We've created an inner loop that completes, but there is no way to get the completing inner loop to complete in the subscription.

Comment: That's correct, in my example, the stream will not complete until it's source completes (source is `this.updates`). Terminating that stream will terminate everything downstream.